# Return json from .net core api when using NotFound()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to make my web api core return application/json, but it strangely always returns this html page breaking the error convention established by the team.

Here's the code i'm trying to execute but with no success at all so far:

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" });
        });

        services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
            {
                var errorList = (from item in actionContext.ModelState
                                 where item.Value.Errors.Any()
                                 select item.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage).ToList();
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(new
                {
                    ErrorType = "bad_request",
                    HasError = true,
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    Message = "Formato do request inválido",
                    Result = new
                    {
                        errors = errorList
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

        app.UseCors(
            options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
        );

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

AuthController.cs

```
[HttpPost("refreshtoken")]
public IActionResult PostRefreshToken(Guid token)
{
    if (!_authTokenService.IsValid(token))
    {
        return NotFound(new JsonResponse
        {
            HasError = true,
            ErrorType = "not_found",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
            Title = "Token não encontrado",
            Message = "refresh is not valid because it was not found or does not comply",
        });
    }

    var savedToken = _authTokenService.Get(token);
    ...

    return Ok(new JsonResponse
    {
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Title = "Token atualizado",
        Message = "jwt access token refreshed with success, please update your keys for subsequent requests",
        Result = new
        {
            Expiration = accessToken.Expiration.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
            AccessToken = accessToken.Token,
            RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token,
         }
    });
}
```

when this code is executed i was expecting a json result when NotFound() block is reached, but instead it returns this text/html page

[image]

ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            HasError = true,
            StatusCode = (int)code,
            Message = ex.Message
        }, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            }
        });

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your API behavior will return a JSON result but will (correctly) keep the status code from the response. Then, your custom middleware `ErrorHandlingMiddleware` will just see the failed status code and transform the result to whatever it does. – You will have to add an exception to your API routes so that your error handling middleware does not run for them.

Comment: yes, i did. I make the 404 by returning NotFound when an entity is not found but the response of this http result is the only one i'm having problems returning a html

Comment: @poke It just does not hit my ErrorHandlingMiddleware, it straight returns html when i use NotFound

Comment: Then where does this text come from? ASP.NET Core doesn’t display such a text and there is no default handling for 404. Can you share your middleware?

Comment: @poke that's the weird part, i updated the question with the error middleware

Comment: Okay, that’s really odd. Do you host your application directly, or is there another server that could produce this result? Can you actually confirm that your server is sending this response and it’s not the browser doing this? Check the browser dev tools, and also the ASP.NET Core server logs to see what response is being produced. The logs also show the content type of the response, so that should give an indication where this might come from.

Comment: @poke i'm using iis express directly from visual studio debug and have tested in kestrel as well, but with same results: the same page is returned. I think i'm gonna have to find another status to represent this situation

Comment: I just made a new test in a brand new project with .net core 3 and it worked like i expected, the project that is giving error has .net core 3.1. Probably there's a bug in one of the packages, i gonna investigate a litle bit more and try to close the question later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it ended up being the visual studio extension **Conveyor by Keyoti** being the culprit of the errors aforementioned.

When i disabled the extension, the code was revealed to be ok and returning the right code, a json object body sent by the server.